# How are native libraries added to the classpath. (JNA)

Tags: java, java-native-interface, classpath, jna

From the JNA Javadoc:

> **Library Search Paths** 
>   A search for a given library will scan the following locations:
>
> 1. `jna.library.path` User-customizable path
> 2. `jna.platform.library.path` Platform-specific
>      paths
> 3. On OSX, `~/Library/Frameworks`, 
>      `/Library/Frameworks`, and 
>      `/System/Library/Frameworks` will be searched for a
>      framework  with a name corresponding to that requested.  Absolute
>      paths to frameworks  are also accepted, either ending at the framework
>      name (sans ".framework")  or the full path to the framework shared
>      library  (e.g. CoreServices.framework/CoreServices).
> 4. Context class loader classpath.  Deployed native libraries
>      may be  installed on the classpath under 
>      `${os-prefix}/LIBRARY_FILENAME`, where
>      `${os-prefix}`  is the OS/Arch prefix returned by `Platform.getNativeLibraryResourcePrefix()`.
>      If bundled in a jar file, the  resource will be extracted to
>      `jna.tmpdir` for loading, and  later removed (but only if
>      `jna.nounpack` is false or not set).
>
> You may
>   set the system property `jna.debug_load=true` to make  JNA
>   print the steps of its library search to the console.

Point 4 says that libraries can be loaded from the classpath, even if I do not add them. My question is how do these libraries (for my example OpenGL32.dll) end up on the java classpath, and how can one tell if a specified library is contained on the classpath.

Comment: _"how do these libraries (for my example OpenGL32.dll) end up on the java classpath"_ -- you put them there?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Where does it say "even if you do not add them"? JNA will search the classpath for libraries, but *someone* has to put them there.